regex to find non-price consecutive digits not immediately after certain word for Apple Numbers
0
How to find invoice number from different companies which may have different order of invoice number, unit cost and total cost?
Following is specific example of a company XYZ which I need to get 1234545
This is invoice from company XYZ - 1234545 product name , product number 444456, information invoice unit cost $12.0 and invoice total $1343.00
Another company may have following invoice This is invoice from company ABC - 1234545 product name and information invoice total cost $6777 and invoice unit cost $654
Apple Numbers do not allow \K which is PCRE answer XYZ.*?\K\d+

What is “Apple Numbers”?

@Toto kind of Excel for Mac

XYZ.*?(\d+)


Dot . Matches any character except line breaks.
* Quantifier. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
? Lazy. Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
( Capturing group #1. Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference
\d Digit. Matches any digit character (0-9).
+ Quantifier. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.#regex

